# curl command to php

Tags: php, curl

I want to use this curl command (works with Windows curl)

```
curl -k -i -H "Accept: application/json" https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/registryList
```

inside php curl.
I tried this code:

```
<?php
 $url="https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/registryList";

 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: application/json']);


 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 var_dump($result);
```

But I don't get any json only html source code.
I think I am using the `-H` and the `-k` option, right? Don't know how to add `-i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a library such as [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) to connect to the api?

In your command line, you use the Accept HTTP header, which negociate the content type of the response, but in your curl option you are using Content-Type, saying any information in your request body is in JSON, nothing about the response type you want.
I therefore would have an extra line such as:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to 1 to get the returned data.

From the document

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the
>   return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);


$url="https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/registryList";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

UPDATE : Its returning html content instead of JSON

So Content-type should be Accept

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but I get the html file which is the same like https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/registryList

Answer (score 1):

The name of the header you're sending is different in the two commands. The working `curl` command line has `Accept: application/json`, but your PHP code has `Content-type: application/json`.